# Антипод event.stopPropagation. Как продолжить всплытие события?

Tags: javascript, html

Есть ли такой метод? Или надо создавать свой event?

**UPD**
Вообщем, применить этот трюк я хочу на компоненте Vue, который не успевает обработать данные, между кликом и открытием окна загрузки файлов (меняется accept).
Но так же, это может понадобиться в том случае, когда вопрос о дальнейшем распространении, нужно решить после какой-нибудь асинхронной операции, например, после ответа сервера...

```js
document.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
  console.log('Клик вспыл до документа')
})
const base = document.getElementById('base');
base.addEventListener("click", (e)=>{
  e.stopPropagation();
  setTimeout(()=>{
// как продолжить всплытие клика?
  })
})
```

```css
body{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#base{
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
 <div id="base"></div>
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93859/discussion-on-question-by---event-stoppropagation--).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Вариант с отменой действия по умолчанию

Открытие диалогового окна для выбора файла можно предотвратить при помощи `event.preventDefault()`. Отменить действие `event.preventDefault()` можно при помощи `event.returnValue = true`

```js
document.querySelector("input").addEventListener("click", async (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  event.returnValue = true;
});
```

```html
<input type="file">
```

Однако стоит учитывать, что если выполняется какая-нибудь асинхронная операция, то по ее завершению восстановить стандартное поведение при помощи `returnValue` уже **не удастся**. Почему? Потому что событие уже давно завершилось, а обработчик исполняет *асинхронный* код (на момент исполнения которого события более не существует)

```js
document.querySelector("input").addEventListener("click", async (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
   
  new Promise((res) => {
    // симулируем асинхронную операцию
    setTimeout(res, 1000);
  }).then(() => {
    console.log("Асинхр. операция завершилась");
    event.returnValue = true;
  });
});
```

```html
<input type="file">
```

### Ваш вариант

К сожалению, так, как вы себе это представляете, тоже ничего **не получится**. Причины 2: первая - такого (стандартного) метода не существует (1), и (2) - вы все так же пытаетесь взаимодействовать с (уже прошедшим, завершившимся) событием асинхронно.

### Что делать? *(рабочий вариант)*

Скорее всего сработает вариант с выбросом кастомного события на другом элементе (см. комментарии к вопросу), однако и там есть свои подводные камни, которые стоит рассмотреть (см. туда же).

Набросал пример, который, вроде бы работает (открывает диалоговое окно через 2 секунды).

```js
document.querySelector("#fake").addEventListener("click", async (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  
  new Promise((res) => {
    setTimeout(res, 2000);
  }).then(() => {
    document.querySelector("#real").click();
  });
});
```

```html
<input type="file" id="fake">
<input type="file" id="real" hidden>
```

Comment: кажется, надобность такого метода говорит о не правильной архитектуре. Почему компонент А должен дожидаться компонента B? Почему, компонент B просто не передаст вызов компоненту А? В случае с модальным окном и ссылкой, почему ссылка подгружает данные, а другой компонент открывает модальное окно? Почему не делать это в одном месте?

Comment: @ThisMan нет-нет-нет, архитектура-то неправильная, я согласен, но как по мне, то неправильная она только потому, что пользователя заставляют дожидаться **нативного** события (что его откладывают). Если у пользователя не открывается диалоговое окно тогда, когда оно должно открыться, то он (по крайней мере лично я) первым делом подумает, что у него комп залагал (ОС в целом или браузер), а не что так и надо.

Comment: а как возобновление всплытия решает эту проблему? Пользователь так же будет дожидаться, более того, в случае с ожиданием, нельзя будет показать лоадер/спинер/анимацию у окна, так как до этого обработчика даже не дошла еще очередь. Суть асинхронного кода в том, что он асинхронный и ничего не блокирует

Comment: @ThisMan так я об этом и говорю :) И пример я привел (в конце поста) именно такой, где все асинхронно работает.

Comment: Я просто о том, что было бы намного правильнее (по крайней мере я так думаю) сразу же показывать диалоговое окно при нажатии на кнопку, при этом тут же начинать асинхронный запрос, сразу же менять содержимое кнопки на какой-нибудь лоадер, а уже по завершению АЗ восстанавливать состояние кнопки и начинать работать с файлами.

Answer (score 1):

Часть событий можно повторить программно - такие как `click` - даже вызовом метода, события посложнее - через `dispatchEvent`, но с некоторыми событиями ничего хорошего не получится.

```js
document.querySelector('section').addEventListener('click', function (e) {
  console.log("Section clicked")
})

~function () {
  var isReplay;

  document.querySelector('div').addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    if (!isReplay) {
      console.log("Div clicked by user")
      e.stopPropagation()
      setTimeout(function () {
        isReplay = true
        e.target.click()
        isReplay = false
      }, 1000)
    }
  })
}()
```

```html
<section><div>123</div></section>
```

Comment: ждем теперь вопроса "что значит `~function ()`"

Comment: @ThisMan, почему ждём?)

Comment: @ThisMan, уже есть дубликат где это поясняется :)